# How to validate an email id in xml schema

Tags: xml, validation, email, schema

Hi I have created a schema to check for email id. which can validate if the email id is abc@def.com and adbc@def.co.in and abc@def.co.in.pune 
But i want to validate only abc@def.com and adbc@def.co.in  because i think email can have maximum 2 dots after @ symbol
so the third one will be invalid email id
So how to validate an email id using schema
Below is the schema

```
<xsd:element name="SSEM" minOccurs="0">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CNT" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="EM" minOccurs="1" nillable="true" type ="singleEmailID"/>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: `because i think email can have maximum 2 dots after @ symbol`. Maybe read relevant RFCs instead of guessing and arbitrarily failing validation? `abc@10.0.0.0` is a perfectly valid e-mail too. http://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You  will need to define a pattern to match against valid e-mails. Patterns are defined using regular expression syntax. Once you have defined a simple type (based on `xs:string`) with the appropriate pattern, you can use that for your e-mail type.

There are several places on the Internet that provide some examples of such types and patterns. An example of an e-mail type is provided [here](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XMLSchemaTutorial/Output/ser_types_st4.html).

The example given there is as follows (I've edited it slightly to make things a little clearer):

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 

  <xsd:element name="A" type="emailAddress"/> 

  <xsd:simpleType name="emailAddress"> 
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> 
      <xsd:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+"/> 
    </xsd:restriction> 
  </xsd:simpleType> 
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: If you only want def.com and def.co.in you should play with this expression a little.

Answer (score 7):

You could use a `<xs:simpleType>` based on a string and with a regex pattern to validate your e-mail addresses:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="emailAddress">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Use any e-mail regex you like :-), see some samples on [RegexLib.Net](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx).

Then, use that type in your basic XML schema:

```
<xsd:element name="email" type="emailAddress" />
```

Could by checked by online validator: https://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html

Comment: Unlike other RegEx libraries, XML Schema patterns do not start with ^ and end with a $.  This is implicit in atomic strings.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below schema validator for email id validation

```
<xsd:simpleType name="emailAddress">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Comment: That works only for a simple email address.

Answer (score 0):

Use this validator for email validation with apostrophe also:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="emailAddress">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:pattern value="^([0-9a-zA-Z_\.\'\-]+)*@[0-9a-zA-Z\-]+[a-zA-Z\.]+Dollar symbol"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

It will work as email validation with apostrophe:-)