# XML Schema for multiple email recipients

Tags: regex, xml, xsd, email-address

I need a sample XSD to support multiple email recipients in a new element. I require each recipient email address in a different element. Can anyone help me with explanation?

**Example**:

```
<EmailReceipts> 
    <address1></address1>
    <address2></address2>
</EmailReceipts>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend not embedding an index number in the `address` elements:

```
<EmailReceipts> 
  <address>john@example.com</address>
  <address>mary@example.org</address>
</EmailReceipts>
```

Then this XSD will validate the above XML (as well as other XML documents with additional `address` elements):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="EmailReceipts">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="address" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The above XSD will allow any string contents for the `address` elements.  If you've like to be more strict, you could use a regular expression to limit the values for `address`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="EmailReceipts">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="address" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="EmailAddressType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="EmailAddressType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

Note that the above regular expression is [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2147904/290085) of [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2147780/290085) possible, each having various degrees of generality and specificity over a [syntax that is more involved than you might imagine](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4).