# Validation on zelle element in xslt

Tags: regex, xsd, xsd-validation

I want to do validation on element where it accepts either phone number or email address. I am using below pattern but its throwing schema validation issue.

```
[_\-a-zA-Z0-9\.\+][a-z|A-Z|0-9|@?](\.?[\-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*
```

Expected result is this element accepts  Ex: either 1234567890 or abc@gmail.com

Comment: Try `([_a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]@[a-zA-Z0-9][_a-zA-Z0-9.+-]*(\.[-a-zA-Z0-9]*[a-zA-Z0-9])*|[0-9]+)`. I was trying to follow your pattern. If you are not married to this regex, you can try `(\S+@\S+\.\S+|[0-9]+)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^(\d+|\w+@\w+\.com)$
```

Or

```
^(\d+|\w+@\w+\.\w+)$
```

Demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/wGJ3uv/1).

Where

- `^` - Match start of string
- Outer `(...)` - Group where we will get either a number or an email
- `\d+` - Match only numbers
- `|` - Or
- `\w+@\w+\.com` - Match text that is separated by `@` and ends with `.com`.

Comment: Your regex is producing below:

Comment: when I gave abc@gmail.com its giving
abcgmail.com
but I need regex which accepts either abc@gmail.com or 123456890 for a zelle element and it wont throw schema validation.

Comment: I'm not sure why the `@` sign was omitted as I tried it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wGJ3uv/1) and it was captured. Perhaps you can try escaping the `@` sign by putting a slash `\@` and see what happens?

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify both patterns in a single regex. XML Schema has a feature designed for exactly this purpose:

```
<xs:simpleType name="emailAddressType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="your chosen regex for an email address"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="phoneNumberType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="your chosen regex for a phone number"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="emailOrPhoneType"
    <xs:union memberTypes="emailAddressType phoneNumberType"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

You may find this thread useful when choosing your regex for an email address: [How to validate an email id in XML schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2147780/how-to-validate-an-email-id-in-xml-schema)

Comment: I tried this but this is failing for phone number always. Ex: 1234567890 or 123-456-7890

Comment: <xsd:simpleType name="emailAddressType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="phoneNumberType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:pattern value="\([0-9]{3}\) [0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
  <xsd:simpleType name="zelletype">
    <xsd:union memberTypes="emailAddressType phoneNumberType"/>
  </xsd:simpleType>

Comment: @jon: please test your phone number regex separately (there are free regex testers online). When you have got it working, test with the full schema. And please, _please_ remember to quote error messages. Just saying 'it is failing' does not provide enough information.